# Change message default @Html.ValidationMessageFor mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I try to change the message default from `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`. Where is the file who i can chage the message: `The _nameFied field is required.`

View:

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumDoc,"", new { @class = "error-input"})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in your modal class's specific property using the [ErrorMessage property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the of `Required` attribute.

Ex:

```
public class MyClass{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "My validation error message goes here")] //give your validation message here
    [Display(Name = "My display name")] //Give your display name here
    public int NumDoc{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i can also put the field name in the message?

Comment: @CesarMiguel What do you mean by new migration? How does your class look like?

Comment: @CesarMiguel Yes you can add `[DisplayName("My Name")]` attribute on top of your property as well.

Comment: Yes, ty

`[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [Display(Name = "Nº Documento")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "É obrigatório")]
        public int NumDoc { get; set; }`